# How to use a progress bar shows the `git clone` progress by NSTask in cocoa

Tags: swift, git, macos

I want to use the progress bar shows the clone progress . I can get nothing by use my code. Hope someone can help me

```
let pro = Process()
pro.launchPath = "/bin/bash"
pro.arguments = ["-c", "cd  /Users/admin/Documents; git clone https://gitee.com/gjesse/laravel.git"]

pro.terminationHandler = { pro in
    print("clone finish")
}

let pip = Pipe()
pro.standardOutput = pip

let file = pip.fileHandleForReading
file.readInBackgroundAndNotify()

NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: NSNotification.Name.NSFileHandleDataAvailable, object: file, queue: nil) { notification in
    let output = file.readDataToEndOfFile()
    print("log\(String(describing: String(data: output, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)))log")
}
pro.launch()
pro.waitUntilExit()
```

Comment: What's wrong with your code? Which error do you have?

Comment: I can not get the logs.

Answer (score 1):

I use this function for any tasks:

```
@discardableResult
private func process(launchPath: String? = nil, arguments: [String]) throws -> String? {
    let process = Process()
    if let launchPath = launchPath {
        process.currentDirectoryPath = launchPath
    }
    process.launchPath = "/usr/bin/env"
    process.arguments = arguments

    var errorData = Data()

    let outputPipe = Pipe()
    process.standardOutput = outputPipe

    let errorPipe = Pipe()
    process.standardError = errorPipe

    errorPipe.fileHandleForReading.readabilityHandler = { handler in
        let data = handler.availableData
        errorData.append(data)
    }

    process.launch()

    let outdata = outputPipe.fileHandleForReading.readDataToEndOfFile()

    process.waitUntilExit()

    if process.terminationStatus != 0 {
        throw Error.processFailed(status: process.terminationStatus, message: errorData.shellString)
    }

    return String(data: outdata, encoding: .utf8)
}
```

For git clone action, I use this function:

```
func clone(fromPath path: String, toLocalPath localPath: String, branch: String? = nil) throws {
    var arguments = ["git", "clone", path, localPath, "--quiet"]
    if let branch = branch {
        arguments.append(contentsOf: ["-b", branch])
    }
    try process(arguments: arguments)
}
```

For you example, just call:

```
clone(fromPath: "https://gitee.com/gjesse/laravel.git", toLocalPath: "/Users/admin/Documents")
```

Comment: Sorry, I want to use the progress bar shows the clone progress. Not just clone my codes.

Comment: Please, update the question. BTW, you can use `TerminalController` from [Utility](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/articles/44/apple-s-new-utility-library-will-power-up-command-line-apps) for progress bar showing

Comment: Sorry, my description is not clear enough. I have updated the question.